# Wrapping elements in an <a> tag generates hydration error

Tags: next.js

### Intro

Below is an abstraction of my actual code which also has perfectly valid HTML.

```
<div>
    <h1>My Title</h1>
    <p>My Paragraph</p>
    <div>
        ....
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

### Desired Result

Now, what I want to do with the code above is wrap everything in an `<a>` tag. Which I'm sure I've done before. The effect being that hovering and clicking anywhere over the entire `<div>` will activate the link.

```
<a href='mylink'>
    <div>
        <h1>My Title</h1>
        <p>My Paragraph</p>
        <div>
            ....
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

### Actual Result

The link doesn't work and Next.js displays an error `Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server`. It also says that it expected a closing `<div>` tag inside the `<a>` tag.

### What I've Done

- Googled the error
- Checked a dozen times to confirm that all `<div>` tags are closed
- Ran the code through an HTML validator to confirm
- Restarted the server

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Do you actually need a new div?  Cause if base div has styling you are going to get weird formatting errors.  Shouldn't the div hold the link and not the other way around?

Comment: You're right that's a better place for it, but it generates the same error.

Comment: If it is claiming that a div tag is not closed, it might not be closed somehow.  What if you double up a </div> at the end?  But normally a <A> tag is like <A href='location'> WHAT THE LINK READS TO THE SCREEN </a>  so all that DIV and other stuff is not required nor really suppose to be part of the link name I don't think.  I bet because of the div use and mutliple tags, somewhere its adding carriage returns or other things that just shouldn't be in the middle of the link.

Comment: Normally use of something like <label> Title </label> would be better label for a link.